# Touch delegates not called on view when z-index is set to non zero value

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing the chat bubble feature. I want the chat bubble to be on top of all the view controller and shouldn't be affected by screen transition. So I decided to add it as subview to `UIWindow` so far it looks like

[image]

This works great, but if I present view controller instead of push then chat head goes behind the presented view controller. To avoid it I set ZIndex property of chat head layer

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            window.addSubview(chatHead)
            chatHead.layer.zPosition = 1
        }
    }
```

But now though chat head appears on top of presented view controller, its touch delegates like `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` nothing gets called when chat head is above presented ViewController

Adding code of chat head (lot of code might be unnecessary to this question, but just posting it so if someone would like to try it)

```
class ChatHeadView: UIView {
    let headerWidth: CGFloat = 80.0
    let headerHeight: CGFloat = 80.0
    let sideInset: CGFloat = 10.0
    let bottomInset: CGFloat = 10.0
    var cancellationWindowShown = false
    
    lazy var cancellationContainerRect: CGRect = {
        var rect = self.cancelChatView.convert(self.cancelChatView.frame, to: nil)
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + 30
        rect.size.height = 100
        return rect
    }()
    
    lazy var cancellationThreshold: CGFloat = {
        return self.keywindow.frame.maxY - (self.keywindow.frame.maxY / 3)
    }()
    
    lazy var keywindow: UIWindow = {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow ?? UIWindow()
        return window
    }()
    
    lazy var cancelChatView: CancelChatView = {
        if let cancelView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CancelChatView", owner: nil, options: [:])?.first as? CancelChatView {
            return cancelView
        }
        fatalError("Couldnt load")
    }()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        self.cancelChatView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.keywindow.frame.maxY - 140, width: self.keywindow.frame.width, height: 140)
        self.cancelChatView.layer.opacity = 0.0
        self.keywindow.addSubview(self.cancelChatView)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        debugPrint("Touch started")
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self.keywindow)
            if location.y >= cancellationThreshold {
                self.showCancellationWindow()
            }
            else {
                removeCancellationView()
                debugPrint("Removing Cancellation window")
            }
            self.center = location
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self.keywindow)
            self.center = location
            self.snap(to: location)
            self.removeCancellationView()
        }
    }
    
    private func snap(to point: CGPoint) {
        var finalPoint:CGPoint = self.frame.origin
        
        if self.cancellationContainerRect.intersects(self.convert(self.frame, to: nil)) {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        else {
            if finalPoint.x <= self.keywindow.center.x {
                finalPoint.x = self.keywindow.frame.minX + sideInset
            }
            else if finalPoint.x > self.keywindow.center.x {
                finalPoint.x = self.keywindow.frame.maxX - (sideInset + self.headerWidth)
            }
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.6, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.frame.origin = finalPoint
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    private func showCancellationWindow() {
        if cancellationWindowShown == false {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.opacity))
            animation.fromValue = 0.0
            animation.toValue = 0.6
            animation.duration = 0.1
            animation.fillMode = .forwards
            animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
            self.cancelChatView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "reveal")
            self.cancellationWindowShown = true
        }
    }
    
    private func removeCancellationView() {
        if cancellationWindowShown == true {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.opacity))
            animation.toValue = 0.0
            animation.duration = 0.1
            animation.fillMode = .forwards
            animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
            self.cancelChatView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "hide")
            cancellationWindowShown = false
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue Gif (touch not working):**

[image]

As matt has asked for details of how I am presenting ViewController, adding screenshot of storyboard segue configuration

[image]

Comment: How are you presenting the presented view controller? What kind of presentation is it? Is it fullscreen?

Comment: yeah, I am presenting view controller via storyboard (sample blank view controller) with fullscreen configuration, Ill add screen shot to question showing segue config

Comment: So my question is: what if you _don't_ use fullscreen? Try Over Full Screen instead. I don't know if that will solve it but it's worth testing.

Comment: @matt: Sure ill try and keep you posted here, but the idea is to use it as reusable tool so any of our app can use it and I was hoping for solution where I don't have to restrict the user app to some specific presentation :)

Comment: @matt: It works with over current context, please help me understand why is it failing with full screen ? It doesn't work when I use show detail also :| why is already added subview to window looses touches when I use any other presentation other than over current context :|

Comment: Well, you already know the answer. The other forms of presentation do indeed block touches to what is "behind" - and that includes your bubble, even though it is _visible_ in front.

Comment: @matt so no way to do it? I can think of 1 solution. Adding a custom window with `windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1` and then implement hit test to check if touch was on chat bubble and redirect touch event to chat else relay it to window below it but that seems very costly approach, any other better way to achieve it?

Comment: Whatever you do is going to be a hack, since what you're trying to do isn't really supported. :)

Comment: @matt : hehehehe :) but because u know iOS and swift much better than I do, can u help me pick or suggest a hack which is better among those hacks :D