# iOS13+ Creating a constant button on top of every screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I maintain an app SDK that contains a button which should always be displayed on top of all screens in the application, but this functionality broke with iOS 13+ which seems to have changed some internals. The button disappears after changing from the first screen.

```
// My code that does not work anymore 
var applicationWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
... 
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 94, height: 73)
applicationWindow!.addSubview(button)
```

I saw similar posts on SOF suggesting code like
`UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?` but it doesn't work for me, and I'm struggling to create and manage a second UIWindow, any code sample would be really appreciated as I'm only a maintainer and I don't work actively on iOS anymore.

Comment: is your second view controller is being presented rather than being pushed? If yes is it presented with full screen? Take a look at the question I asked sometime back I cant mark it as duplicate because its not answered but it might help u get some info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758485/touch-delegates-not-called-on-view-when-z-index-is-set-to-non-zero-value. One thing I did different though is to use `button.layer. zPosition = 1` which will help u in cases if your view controller is presented with over current context but in other cases you are out of luck

Comment: The problem is I'm maintaining a library so I don't control how UIControllers are managed by clients

Comment: As I said in the comments it works only if present over current context for anything else it will fail. So as of now I guess its a dead end, you cant do much about it. Even if you set zPosition button might be shown on top yet it wont take any touch :| you can try hacks like using `hitTest` `pointInside` in your own window and asking all your clients to use your window instead of `UIWindow` but am sure thats not a feasible solution